# Displaying data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have `employee`, `job` and `application` tables.

I need to display all data from job where a specific employee didn't apply at application table.

```
Employee:
    e_id pk
    e_name

Job:
    j_id pk
    j_name

Application:
    a_id pk
    e_id
    j_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to filter applications for a particular employee.

```
SELECT
    J.j_id,
    J.j_name
FROM
    Job J
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Application A 
                WHERE A.j_id = J.j_id AND A.e_id = 999) -- Specific Employee's ID
```

Comment: $q ="SELECT job.j_id, job.j_name FROM Job 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM application
                WHERE application.j_id = Job.j_id AND application.e_id = '".$_SESSION['eeid']."')";
    $res = mysql_query($q,$link) or die("Wrong Query");

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to filter jobs without certain employee applicated:

```
SELECT j.*
  FROM Job              AS j
  LEFT JOIN Application AS a  ON a.j_id = j.j_id
                             AND a.e_id = _certain_id_
 WHERE a.e_id IS NULL
;
```